# pandas-like operations with index alignment in DolphinDB

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dolphindb

In pandas, if I do binary operations on two DataFrames or Series with different indices, their indices are aligned, and rows with the same index value are computed like this:

```
>>> s1 = pd.Series([1,2,3,4], index=["a","a","b","c"])
>>> s2 = pd.Series([10,20,30,40], index=["a","a","a","c"])
>>> s1 + s2
a    11.0
a    21.0
a    31.0
a    12.0
a    22.0
a    32.0
b     NaN
c    44.0
dtype: float64
```

I would like to know how to do an index-aligned operation in DolphinDB, for example:

```
s1 = table([1,2,3,4] as val, ["a","a","b","c"] as index)
s2 = table([10,20,30,40] as val, ["a","a","a","c"] as index)

// How do I do an index-aligned add operation?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use DolphinDB Orca API

```
import dolphindb.orca as orca
s1=orca.Series([1,2,3,4], index=["a","a","b","c"])
s2=orca.Series([10,20,30,40], index=["a","a","a","c"])
s1+s2
>>> s1+s2
a    11.0
a    21.0
a    31.0
a    12.0
a    22.0
a    32.0
b     NaN
c    44.0
dtype: float64
```